# Dimensionality of space given N points and distances between them

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A dilettante question here.

Let's say we have N points and distances between them. All distances are non-zero and are defined for all pairs.

What should be the dimensionality of space where all points can be properly placed, given the distances between them?

I think there are two subquestions here: (1) what should be the dimensionality in a general case, i.e. given arbitrary distances? and (2) how can dimensionality be reduced in specific cases, i.e. with specific constant distances? I'm more interested in (1). So:

For 2 points the 1-dimensional space is sufficient.

For 3 points it would be a triangle in the 2-dimensional space.

However the 4-point case already seems complicated to me, since (intuitively) the 3-dimensional space is not sufficient for placing 4 points. We can form 2 triangles with a shared side, meaning that the distance between the two "free-hanging" vertices can not have an arbitrary distance between them. If this is correct, does it mean the 4-dimensional space would be sufficient?

And finally, what about N number of points with arbitrary distances between them?

Comment: Euclidean distance?

Comment: @mvw I don't know of any others :)

Comment: This problem seems to be: Given all $\DeclareMathOperator{dist}{dist}\dist(P_i, P_j)>0$ for $N$ points $P_i$, decide if it is possible to assign $n$ dimensional coordinates to each point, such that the given distances result.

Comment: @mvw I think my question is slightly different: what is the smallest dimensionality  where coordinates can be assigned to all points given arbitrary distances? I.e. the general case.

Comment: P.S. a problem where you could find for example that N points can be placed in a 1-dimensional space for a specific matrix of distances is a different problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000006/minimum-dimension-to-hold-n-points-with-given-distances) answer your question?

Comment: @A.Γ. looks a bit too complicated to me, I would appreciate a simplified answer, in "layman terms". (And if it's true that the problem has no general solution then it would be interesting to create an N-dimensional space where it does?)

Comment: @mojuba You may also look through Related question in the link above to the right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum dimension to hold $N$ points with given distances?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000006/minimum-dimension-to-hold-n-points-with-given-distances)

Answer (score 0):

We assume that we are using Euclidean spaces. The problem with "given arbitrary distances" becomes apparent with 3 points. The three distances must satisfy the triangle inequality, thus the distances can not be completely arbitary. This requirement does **not** depend on the dimension of the Euclidean space. That is, if the triangle inequality is **not** satisfied, there is no way to embed the 3 points in any Euclidean space. Read the Wikipedia article [Inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

A similar situation arises for 4 points which you mentioned. The distance between the two "free-hanging" vertices can not have an arbitrary distance. It has to satisfy an inequality also. Similarly, if that inequality is not satisfied, there is no way to embed the 4 points in any Euclidean space. Read the Wikipedia article [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) for details about Ptolemy's inequality.

Comment: OK, but is there a proof that no such Euclidean space exists for arbitrary distances between, say, only 3 points? N points?